# Sorting in XamGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, xamgrid

We are working on WPF project with MVVM architecture. And we are using XamGrid. We have bound a Data Table in xamGrid Item source. I want to perform sorting programmatically on the column of the xamGid on the basis of column value.
We are using following code to sort the column:

```
if (xamGrid != null)
{
   if (associatedColumn != null)
   {
      xamGrid.SortingSettings.SortedColumns.Clear();
      xamGrid.SortingSettings.SortingSettings.SortedColumns.Add(Column);
      xamGrid.SortingSettings.SortingSettings.FirstSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
    }
 }
```

I need some other standard way to sort in XamGrid.

Comment: That's kind of vague.  What's wrong with the way you're currently doing it?  What kind of "other standard way" are you looking for, precisely?  What problem with your existing method should it overcome?

Comment: IN xamGrid no other way to sort column?

Comment: Don't answer my question with a question.  Please provide an answer to what I asked.

Comment: In my case we have a content pane and with it we have a xamGrid and some buttons. We have other control from where we are refreshing sorting and when the Content pane is not in view UI was hung while we call this method to sort.

Comment: Is there is any alternate way of Sorting in XamGrid?